# Problems with routes and browserHistory.push

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm trying to build a single page app and I encountered some problems with Routes.

In the code bellow I'm checking if I already have a Token, and if I don't, I redirect the user to the login page with browserHistory.push.

The url get updated to "http://localhost:xxxx/login#/?_k=yyyyy" but the page doesn't refresh.

```
//Home.js
import React from "react";
import docCookies from "docCookies";
import { Router, browserHistory } from "react-router";

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
          console.log("Component mounted");
        if (docCookies.getItem("token")) {
            console.log("token found"); // If a token is found render should fire
        }
        else {
            console.log("Tryng to transition");
            browserHistory.push("/login"); //Trying to redirect to the login page
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (<h1>This is home</h1>);
    }
 }
```

EDIT: This is the file where my routes are defined

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Router, hashHistory, IndexRoute} from "react-router";

import Home from "./home/Home";
import Login from "./login/Login";

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {token: ""};
   }

   render() {
       return (
          <div>
             <Router history={hashHistory}>
                 <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                 <Route path="login" component={Login} />
             </Router>
          </div>
      )};
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your routes code? What log appears at console?

Comment: The console is logging "Component mounted, Tryng to transition" and "THIS IS HOME" is displayed on the page

Comment: Try change hashHistory for browserHistory

Comment: Still isn't working :/

Comment: You can access your application: localhost/login ?

Comment: No i can't I get a 404.

Comment: There is the problem, your route to login should be <Route path="/login" component={Login} />. Try it and tell me if you got

Comment: seems, i have conflicts with mvc's routes

Comment: Check your login component and if your components are at the path that you are passing to your components